# Remove default REST services from Jersey

Tags: rest, netbeans, service, jersey

I created a REST Service using netbeans 7.1 with Jersey 1.8 and inside the "RESTful Web Services" folder it added 2 services:

- AccessTokenRequest [/accessToken]
- RequestTokenRequest [/requestToken]

I tried clicking with right button to delete or pressing delete on keyboard but they won't go away... any clues on how to delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu that appears after right-clicking a service name, there should be an "*open*" option. Clicking it will take you to the the class, where the resource is defined. Removing the jersey annotations from its methods will make it disappear from the "*RESTful Web Services*" folder (as well as render them unavailable for clients). If you don't need the class, you can simply delete it all. Be sure to check for dependencies as you do it.

Comment: It is included in netbeans jersey bundle, selecting only the needed classes solved it! Thanks!